# Use HJKL in menus of JetBrains IDEs

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

Is it possible to use J and K when choosing a suggested auto-completion item? See the image below: I'd like to, maybe hold ALT or SHIFT (or in some other way differentiate between moving and typing), and use J and K to select the proper suggestion.

[image]

Is anything similar also available for moving around the menus (in Project view etc.)?

Comment: No, in popup dialogs it is not possible to remap navigation keys: [IDEA-108609](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-108609). May be this plugin could help: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9852-ijkl-shortctus

Comment: I'd love this as well.

Comment: @Dakatine I posted an answer how I made this work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to make this work by creating a shortcut *ALT+J* mapped to the *Down* key and *ALT+K* to the *Up* key.

You can move up and down in the popup without needing to move your hand away from HJKL to the arrow keys.

This also works in the *Find in path* window, though it does not work in the navigation menu.

[image]

**Update:** For `Alt + K` to work in the Find window since the version 2020+, one has to disable mnemonics in Settings, under `Appearance & Behaviour` -> `Appearance` -> `Disable mnemonics in controls`.

Answer (score 3):

@Rok Povsic's solution is great and I used it a bit, but in some pop up menus like Intention actions, refactoring menu or usages the trick won't work.

**So I used this [Power Toys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/releases/) program from Microsoft to remap the Alt+J, Alt+K, Alt+H, Alt+L to arrow keys at windows level and now this works great everywhere around the IDE.**

You can even specify only the app in which you want to override this shortcuts. For example for rider it will be "rider64.exe". You can find the name of the app you want to use in task manager under "Details".

[image]